# Local truncation error for trapezoidal rule

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, truncation-error

Find the local truncation error for the Trapezoidal rule, and hence find the order of the method. What do you expect would happen to
the local errors if we were to halve the step size h used ? Explain your answer.

I've found the truncation error, but I'm having trouble finding the order and explaining what would happen if I were to halve the step size.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Depends on the function. The Trapezoidal rule may overestimate or underestimate due to concavity.

Comment: Yn+1 - Yn = h/2 (Fn+1+Fn). Not sure if that's clear enough as I'm unsure how to type subscripts

Comment: One easy way to determine the error is to use taylor expansion. Every term has a certain "rest term". Most of these will cancel out, but only the $\mathbb{O}(c)$ will stay there that is your error.